# I want to override the Private innerclass method in child class is it possible or any other way to do that?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

Is there any way that I can extend the outer class and override the method?

```
class A {

    public String demofield;

    private class democlass {
        public demomethod() {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Comment: Where's `method1`?

Comment: Title says you want to extend the inner class. Text says you wan't to extend the outer class

Comment: sorry method itself not method1!

Comment: @jhamon here i ,mean that i want to override the method inside the innerclass which is private one thats sit is there any way to do that??

Answer (score 1):

You can only override a private class in the same outer class. e.g.

```
class a {

    public String demofield;

    private class democlass {
        public demomethod() {
        } 
    }

    private class demosubclass extends democlass {
        @Override
        public demomethod() {
        } 
    }
```

The use of `private` prevents it being accessible from any other class.